# Set space between body text and header/footer in memoir class

Tags: header-footer, margins, memoir, geometry, footer

I want to be able to change the vertical space between where the body text ends and where the footer starts, while fixing the margins to be 20mm.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{20mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{20mm}{*}

\setheadfoot{15mm}{\baselineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{\baselineskip}{*}

\def\baselinestretch{1.1}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]
    
\end{document}
```

This does not give enough space between the last line of text on page 1 and the footer showing the page number

[image: example]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I noticed you are loading geometry but not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original configuration `memoir` reports to the log file

```
Text height and width: 737pt by 483pt
Footskip: 14.5pt
```

You can decrease the height of the text by say 29 points and add the same amount to the footskip to keep the bottom margin.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<<

\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{20mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{20mm}{*}

\setheadfoot{15mm}{\baselineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{\baselineskip}{*}
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}

\settypeblocksize{708pt}{483pt}{*} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\footskip}{43.5pt}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}    
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: zz]

Comment: I think you meant to say "decrease the text height" not the width.

Comment: Thankyou! This will work, however I am wondering if there is a way to apply this change only to the first page of a new chapter. On subsequent pages of the chapter, there is no footer, so I don't need the extra space there.